# aspnet_regiis -- Encryption support for web.config /app.config files: Not available on Windows 10?

Tags: .net

When I run aspnet_regiis -? on Windows 10, the various crypto options are not listed (e.g. -pc, -pef, -pdf, etc)

They ARE listed on Server.

This means that I cannot manage .config crypto on Windows 10?  (The place where I most want/need to...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, I see it now.

The version of aspnet_regiis that is in the path lacks the crypto options.

If I first:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

The aspnet_regiis there is the full animal.

Now to figure out the path story...